# Named Range seemingly stopping me Breaking Links

Tags: vba, excel

If the workbook `wbOutput` is free of named ranges then the following will break all links to other workbooks:

```
Dim Link As Variant
Dim myLinks As Variant
myLinks = wbOutput.LinkSources(Type:=Excel.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
For Each Link In myLinks
    wbOutput.BreakLink Name:=Link, Type:=Excel.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next Link
```

If I add just one named range to `wbOutput` then  the above seems to clear links upto, and including the worksheet that contains the named range but worksheets that come after are left with links intact.

Is the scope of the named ranges important?

Why is this happening and how is it rectified?

Comment: Is it possible that the existence of a NamedRange is accompanied by the relevant worksheet being protected? Having a Protected Worksheet *anywhere in the workbook* will interfere with breaking links.  Also, Can you manually break the links in External Links Manager, or dos that suffer the same problem?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens no protected or hidden sheets

Comment: Could there be any *Very Protected* sheets (ie visible only through VBA?)

Comment: I keep seeing suggestions to resolve this issue by copy/pasting the offending ranges 'as values'. you could use a routine with the Find method to clean up after running the code you already have. would this be possible for your situation?

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I could easily do what you suggest but that isn't the question.

Comment: Which language is your Excel, and what's the name of the named range ... sometimes funny things happen ... see my  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254443/excel-vba-behaves-different-in-different-languages

Comment: @MikeD it is in English. I've tried a couple of names which are very simple and nothing like any protected words. The scope of the name seems to have an influence.